# writing output of python cgi.print_environ() and cgi.print_form() to file

Tags: python, cgi

I'm trying to capture the output of `cgi.print_form()` and `cgi.print_environ()` and write them to files for later perusal, but it doesn't seem to be behaving as I'd expect.

I would expect this to simply write the output of the module to the path specified, but what I get is the `cgi.print_form()` output displayed to the page, nothing from `cgi.print_environ()` , the `formpath` file is empty, and the `envpath` file doesn't get created.

When I wrap the module in `str()` I get `None` in both files.

This was supposed to be a quick test to see what I'm getting from a remotely hosted form, but it just isn't working.

It's python 2.7.2

```
formfile = open(formpath, 'w')
formfile.write(cgi.print_form(form))
formfile.close()
envfile = open(envpath, 'w')
envfile.write(cgi.print_environ())
envfile.close()
```

EDIT: Just decided to write my own loop, but am still looking for a way to capture the `print_form` and `print_environ` function output.

```
for item in form:
     key = form.getfirst(item)
     fileitem = form[item]
     if fileitem.filename:
          formfile.write("%s is file %s\n" % (item, fileitem.filename))
          filepath = '../fmtmp/%s_%s_%s' % (tstamp, item, fileitem.filename)
          open(filepath, 'w').write(fileitem.file.read())
     else:
          formfile.write("%s = %s\n" % (item, key))
formfile.close()
envfile = open(envpath, 'w')
for var in os.environ:
     envfile.write("%s = %s\n" % (var, os.environ[var]))
envfile.close()
```

Which gives me the added benny of saving whatever is uploaded as a file.

Comment: If you write your own answer to your question, it's great, but please make it an answer, not an edit. You can accept it later.

Comment: One more thing: `string` is a name of a built-in Python module, maybe using this as a local variable name isn't a very good idea.

Comment: good point, I changed it in the code I implemented, don't know why I left it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `x = cgi.print_environ()` still outputs stuff if run in the interactive prompt (x will be None). CGI is interacting witht the web server over standard in/out. print_environ() is simply printing to standard out. It's point is to make it easy to debug enviroment by printing it in your browser.

EDIT: Actually sending it to file is somewhat tricky. You could try:

```
f = open('file', 'w')
old = sys.stdout
sys.stdout = f
cgi.print_environ()
f.flush()
sys.stdout = old
f.close()
```

Comment: I get that, but how can I capture that output and save it to a file?

Comment: I just went around the functions and bruted it manually. See the edit.